# Gerrit 2.8.5 retrieving xGerritAuth from http request

Tags: http-headers, gerrit

I am a bit of a newbie to Gerrit customization and running tests against Gerrit server.

In 2.4 version of Gerrit, an http login request (in my case from python file) would return a result that had the `xsrfToken` field and value as members of `gerrit_hostpagedata` (e.g. in request result you would see `gerrit_hostpagedata.xsrfToken=<some value>`).

In 2.8, this has changed so that `xGerritAuth` is now the field for the token value. However, the response from the server to my http  login request (via python) is not returning the `xGerritAuth` field/value pair.

In the web UI for Gerrit, if I view the source when logging in, I can see the xGerritAuth field/value pair.

So I am wondering is there a way to get the `xGerritAuth` value returned in the response to the http login request?

NOTE that the `gerrit/common/data/HosptPageData.java` has changed to reflect the new token name (`xGerritAuth`).

thx
-mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the `xGerritAuth` out of the HTML response (which you get when you send your credentials to `/login/`). I do exactly that in my gerrit-rest-java-client. [Check out this code](https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-rest-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/urswolfer/gerrit/client/rest/http/GerritRestClient.java). (`tryGerritHttpAuth` and `extractGerritAuth`).

Another way: use the (new) REST API of Gerrit. There you can use the HTTP credential you set in your Gerrit account settings. [See REST API’s documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice...I will give it a shot once I have gone over your code. What is your setting for AUTH in the gerrit.config? I tried using the rest api via curl commands and I am not having a lot of luck getting it to work with --user switch.  I can get a list of projects returned, but only the anonymous ones...not all the ones that I have permissions to see.  Also using the --anyauth switch in the curl command.

Comment: My code basically supports (almost) all AUTH methods (except OAuth). The xGerritAuth stuff is only required when using the "normal" Gerrit login (but not the HTTP password from Gerrit settings). Using the REST API, I do not use any commands like --anyauth or --user. I just send username and password of the user I want do REST operations with.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use cURL to test the rest api, but I am not having much luck. Were you able to test using cURL? I am just trying to get a list of projects (in my test), but it seems to ignore the --user values I send and just gives me projects with anonymous access.

Comment: finally got a rest api call working with curl...I had to use another version of curl...weird bug with curl...in any event...I am off and running now....thx

Comment: Were you able to use curl to do the /login/ ? I can run curl commands that successfully test the rest api and digest authentication, but I can seem to get xGerritAuth token when I try sending credentials to /login/. I tried curl -v -D-  --user username:password https://someserver.net:443/login/